# Azure Devops - Release Pipeline - 'KubernetesManifest' fails with error - ##[error]error: must specify one of -f and -k

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-aks

1. I am creating a CI/CD pipeline with Azure Container Registry and Azure Kubernetes Cluster.
2. My Docker Build and Push Stage works perfectly fine and I do see a new image in my repository.
3. However my **KubernetesManifest** fails with error

```
: ##[error]error: must specify one of -f and -k

`Starting: KubernetesManifest
==============================================================================
Task         : Deploy to Kubernetes
Description  : Use Kubernetes manifest files to deploy to clusters or even bake the manifest files to be used for deployments using Helm charts
Version      : 1.234.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azpipes-k8s-manifest-tsg
==============================================================================
Connection type: kubernetesServiceConnection
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /usr/bin
==============================================================================
            Kubectl Client Version: v1.29.2
            Kubectl Server Version: v1.27.9
==============================================================================
***/usr/bin/kubectl apply -f  --namespace default
error: must specify one of -f and -k
##[error]error: must specify one of -f and -k***
Finishing: KubernetesManifest
```

4. Here is my YAML File:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'dc1fd675-af3a-4d9e-b1df-cde3d121f673'
  imageRepository: 'todo'
  containerRegistry: 'acr31.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
    - task: KubernetesManifest@1
      inputs:
        action: 'deploy'
        connectionType: 'kubernetesServiceConnection'
        kubernetesServiceConnection: 'aks-service'
        manifests: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Manifest/manifest.yml'
```

5. Here is my manifest file:

```
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Namespace
  metadata:
    name: default-1708943304873
  spec:
    finalizers:
      - kubernetes
- apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: todo
    namespace: default-1708943304873
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: todo
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: todo
      spec:
        nodeSelector:
          kubernetes.io/os: linux
        containers:
          - name: todo
            image: acr31.azurecr.io/todo
            ports:
              - containerPort: 3000
            resources:
              requests:
                cpu: '0'
                memory: '0'
              limits:
                cpu: '256'
                memory: 11400G
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: todo-service
    namespace: default-1708943304873
  spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
      - targetPort: 3000
        name: port3000
        port: 3000
        protocol: TCP
    selector:
      app: todo
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Test the same sample and I can reproduce the same issue.

[image]

The cause of the issue is that the manifest file format has issues.

You need to do the following changes:

1.Change the `- apiVersion: v1` to `apiVersion: v1`. Then move the entire content forward two spaces

2.Since you are combining multiple kinds in one yaml, you need to separate each code block with `---`

Refer to the following sample:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: default-1708943304873
spec:
  finalizers:
    - kubernetes

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: todo
  namespace: default-1708943304873
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: todo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: todo
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      containers:
        - name: todo
          image: acr31.azurecr.io/todo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: '0'
              memory: '0'
            limits:
              cpu: '256'
              memory: 11400G

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: todo-service
  namespace: default-1708943304873
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - targetPort: 3000
      name: port3000
      port: 3000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: todo
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Quickstart: Deploy an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster using Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/learn/quick-kubernetes-deploy-cli)